# the value has to be added and placed in text box without on it in html

Tags: javascript, html

html

```
<input type="text" id="txt1"  onChange="sum();" />
<input type="text" id="txt2"  onChange="sum();" />
<input type="text" id="txt3"   onChange="sum2();" readonly/>
<input type="text" id="txt4"  onChange="sum1();" />
<input type="text" id="txt5"  onChange="sum1();" readonly/>
<input type="text" id="txt6"  onChange="sum2();" readonly/>
<input type="text" id="txt7" />
```

javascript

```
function sum() {
            var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
            var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt2').value;
            var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) + parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
            if (!isNaN(result)) {
                document.getElementById('txt3').value = result;
            }
        }
function sum1() {
            var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt4').value;
            var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt5').value;
            var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) + parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
            if (!isNaN(result)) {
                document.getElementById('txt6').value = result;
            }
        }
function sum2() {
            var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt3').value;
            var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt6').value;
            var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) + parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
            if (!isNaN(result)) {
                document.getElementById('txt7').value = result;
            }
        }
```

this is the code am using am not getting value to txt7 how to get this value can someone help me please.nothing is getting into txt7 textbox i need to get the value of txt3 and txt4 added value

Comment: Please rephrase... and use some punctuation while you're at it... it is impossible to understand your problem...

Answer (score 0):

`onLoad="total_advertising()"` ?

Comment: the values into those to boxes will get from other textboxes

Comment: sorry, but i dont understand your problem? Can you explain it in a bit more words? thanks ;)

Comment: there are more textboxes assume a,b,c,d,e,f,g here the user will enter values into a,b,c,d where the remaining are readonly. a and b values are added and shown in e textbox where as c and are added and shown in f textbox. and these two values are to be added and shown in f textbox. the issue is for a,b,c,d am using onchange and those values are added and shown in e and f. but when clicking on g only e and f added value is showing if not it is not showing in g textbox, i need it to get value without clicking on it any suggestion please.